# Newbie! my app breaks down in if statement: NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, string, ios4, selector, conditional-statements

I am following the Stanford CS193P class and I am trying to do assignment 2. I have now for hours stared at the same error message:

```
-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b373e0,
```

while trying endless revisions of the code

The method running is this one:

```
+ (double)evaluateExpression:(id)anExpression
          usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variables;          
{   
    CalculatorBrain *evalBrain =[[CalculatorBrain alloc]init];
    for (id element in anExpression) {
        if([element isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSString *elementFirst=[element substringToIndex:1];
            if ([elementFirst isEqual:@"v"]) 
            {
                NSString *varLookUp = [element substringFromIndex:0];
                [evalBrain setOperand:[[variables objectForKey:varLookUp]doubleValue]];
            } 
            else 
            {
                [evalBrain performOperation:element];

            }
        }
        if ([element isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            [evalBrain setOperand: [element doubleValue]];
        }   
    }
    return [evalBrain operand];

}
```

it is at the statement

```
if ([elementFirst isEqual:@"v"])
```

the program crashes.

Grateful any hints!

Comment: Printing value of `elementFirst` would help.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's going wrong, but try replacing the whole thing with [element hasPrefix:@"v"]. It might help if something's going wrong in substringToIndex or something :P Also, are you absolutely sure that the error is in that statement?

Comment: Can you try to log the whole "anExpression" and plot the result of see if it crashes? NSLog(@"%@",anExpression). If it crashes, then the problem is in the fact that the anExpression content (what is it, an array, a dictionary?) has been dealloc'd.

Comment: You added an error message, then you cut it off just before it came to the interesting bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ([elementFirst isEqualToString:@"v"])
```

instead.

Comment: I agree with Nikitia then. Throw `NSLog(@"elementFirst: %@", elementFirst);` in there before your if, and see if that gives us anything else to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is result of NSLog on elementfirst:

```
2011-02-06 16:00:11.554 Calculator[14160:207] elementfirst: +
```

it correctly shows that I hit the '+' key which is not equal to 'v' and the program should go to the else block. Unfortunately it crashes in stead...

Comment: Feel like an idiot but somehow i cannot find out how to add a comment on my original post. To hauntsaninja: tried your suggestion as well, and get same negative outcome. I agree it seems weird that the statement should be the real issue, but when i fill NSLogs all around it is at this point it objects?  Jesper

Comment: Thanks all! problem solved. It was an NSLog (that i edited out of the post for readability) that sent a string to a string. Thanks again. Jesper

Comment: You can edit your original post, there's a button on the bottom.

Comment: @Nikita Thanks. I think I lost the access to the original post when I inadvertently answered on my own and at the same time was not registered as a user. I have registered in the meantime so next time it will probably work better than this mess :-)...